# How to add header tabs in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Please how do I achieve this in Ionic Framework? http://s8.postimg.org/6gg621f1h/Screenshot_2016_02_26_10_24_53.png

I am fairly new to ionic but I think I understanding the routing. Please kindly guide me on how to add tab buttons and horizontal sliders. Please refer to pic.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the tabs button you could use the buttons-headers-footers on this page and for  the horizontal slider you could use the button-bar: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Put the button-bar under the buttons headers.

For all the icons, you can use the Ionicons: http://ionicons.com/

I hope this can help you!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you man. You are great. I followed your instructions and I was able to add the sample code in index.html and it worked.

Comment: Please can you check this link. I need your assistance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918923/magento-ionic-app-filtering-categories-and-pages